# Create a new file as a copy of an existing file in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, I created a file as a template. Every time I create a temporary file based on this template, I need to:

- open the template file,
- copy its contents,
- open a new file, and
- paste the contents

before I can begin to edit the temporary file.

I don't need to save the temporary file, so I will not copy the template file in Windows Explorer.

Is there a way to "Copy and Create" in Notepad++, to copy the contents of the template file to create a new file?

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood you question. But if you don't need to save the copy of the file. Couldn't you just set the template file to Read Only?

Comment: That's a good idea, Dracs. So that I can modify directly the template instead of copy it first. But when I create two files at the same time from one template, I need to copy from it anyway.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Didn't consider needing more than one copy of the template at once.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a plugin called NewFileBrowser that will allow you to create up to two templates. There is a review of it [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/create-custom-file-templates-for-programming-in-notepad-plugin/)

There is also a [Snippet Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snippetplus/) that you could use to duplicate your template functionality. Simply create a snippet for each template that you want and then when you create a new file apply the desired snippet to the blank page.

Comment: Thank you for the link. However I have 30+ templates for different tasks. The plugin limits the templates to 2.

Comment: @ning updated answer with another option.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the Snippet Plugin. It's for coding, and I will confirm how to make it fit in my usage. Thank you.